# node-apn logs is not getting stored in file

Tags: node.js, logging, apple-push-notifications

I need to debug the node-apn (some pushes are getting lost), so i need to analyze node-apn logs. Therefore, i want to store node-apn logs in a file.

**What i have tried**

I have enabled the node-apn logs and they are appearing on my console. Now, i am running following commands to start the server but i could not see node-apn logs in the file. I can see application logs (generated by winston) in file.

```
sudo node app.js test >> /home/gaurav/temp.txt
sudo node app.js test | tee /home/gaurav/temp.txt
```

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are probably being sent to stderr instead of stdout, so try this:

```
sudo node app.js test >> /home/gaurav/temp.txt 2>&1
sudo node app.js test 2>&1 | tee /home/gaurav/temp.txt
```

The `2>&1` redirects everything being sent to stderr to stdout.